# NullPointerException in hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getBlockIndex when chaining two jobs

Tags: java, hadoop, nullpointerexception, mapreduce

I am trying to build inverted index.

I chain two jobs.

Basically, the first job parses the input and cleans it, and stores result in a folder 'output' which is the input folder to the second job.

The second job is supposed to actually build the inverted index.

When I just had the first job, it worked fine (at least, there were no exceptions).

I chain two jobs like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String inputPath = args[0];
        String outputPath = args[1];
        String stopWordsPath = args[2];
        String finalOutputPath = args[3];

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();    
        conf.set("job.stopwords.path", stopWordsPath);

        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Tokenize");

        job.setJobName("Tokenize");
        job.setJarByClass(TokenizerMapper.class);

        job.setNumReduceTasks(1);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(inputPath));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputPath));

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(PostingListEntry.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(PostingListEntry.class);

        job.setOutputFormatClass(MapFileOutputFormat.class);

        job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(TokenizerReducer.class);

        // Delete the output directory if it exists already.
        Path outputDir = new Path(outputPath);
        FileSystem.get(conf).delete(outputDir, true);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        job.waitForCompletion(true);
        System.out.println("Job Finished in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000.0 + " seconds");

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

        Configuration conf2 = new Configuration();    

        Job job2 = Job.getInstance(conf2, "BuildIndex");

        job2.setJobName("BuildIndex");
        job2.setJarByClass(InvertedIndexMapper.class);

        job2.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        job2.setNumReduceTasks(1);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job2, new Path(outputPath));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, new Path(finalOutputPath));

        job2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job2.setOutputValueClass(PostingListEntry.class);

        job2.setMapperClass(InvertedIndexMapper.class);
        job2.setReducerClass(InvertedIndexReducer.class);

        // Delete the output directory if it exists already.
        Path finalOutputDir = new Path(finalOutputPath);
        FileSystem.get(conf2).delete(finalOutputDir, true);

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // THIS LINE GIVES ERROR: 
        job2.waitForCompletion(true);
        System.out.println("Job Finished in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000.0 + " seconds");
    }
}
```

I get an

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getBlockIndex(FileInputFormat.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:196)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
    at Main.main(Main.java:79)
```

What is wrong with this configuration, and how should I chain the jobs?

Comment: It is hard to tell exactly what is wrong. Could you please post or upload somewhere (GitHub?) the entire source code to be able to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Please take a look: https://github.com/Oleksandra28/BuildInvertedIndex/tree/master/VectorSpaceRetrievalSystem/src. Now I have an error even executing the first job (TokenizeMapper and TokenizeReducer are used). I think there might be something wrong with how I am using ArrayListWritable class that I have taken from here: https://lintool.github.io/Cloud9/ I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: Thank you for posting the source code! Could you please point out what command-line arguments (their exact value) should be used in order to run the program?

Comment: first command-line arg:`/Users/osopova/Documents/00_KSU_Masters/00_2016_Fall/01_Information_Retrieval/02_prog_1/VectorSpaceRetrievalSystem/data/cranfield.txt`       second command-line arg: `output`    third command-line arg:   `/Users/osopova/Documents/00_KSU_Masters/00_2016_Fall/01_Information_Retrieval/02_prog_1/VectorSpaceRetrievalSystem/stopwords/stopwords_smaller_list.txt`          forth command-line arg:    `finaloutput`        -- in my laptop, it is like this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't clear if you're intentionally using `MapFileOutputFormat` as the output format in the first job. The more common approach is to use `SequenceFileOutputFormat` with `SequenceFileInputFormat` as the input format in the second job.

At the moment, you've specified `MapFileOutputFormat` as the output to the first job with no input specified in the second, so it will be `TextInputFormat` which is unlikely to work.

Looking at your `TokenizerReducer` class the signature for the `reduce` method is incorrect. You have:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<PostingListEntry> values, Context context)
```

It should be:

```
public void reduce(Key key, Iterable<PostingListEntry> values, Context context)
```

Because of this it won't be calling your implementation, so it will just be an identity reduce.

Comment: the reason I used `MapFileOutputFormat` is because I was following the approach here: https://github.com/lintool/bespin/blob/master/src/main/java/io/bespin/java/mapreduce/search/BuildInvertedIndex.java

Comment: @Oleksandra i added an update for you after having a quick look at your code.